# how use an onclick with FlowPanel?

Tags: gwt

I tried this code:

```
public class OwnFlowPanel extends FlowPanel implements HasClickHandlers{
 public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
  return addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
 }
}
```

and then I used this in another class:

```
OwnFlowPanel panel = new OwnFlowPanel();

panel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
  Window.alert("Clicked on object id: "+id);
 }
});
```

This didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! I restarted Eclipse's server and it works now :-P

Answer (score 0):

You could also just put the `FlowPanel` into a `FocusPanel` (call `setWidget()`).

Comment: will it make any difference in loading time? (its 3 panels)

Comment: not sure, but i guess it will. but i doubt that this will be recognizable by the user.